# Does life insurance cover suicide?

Tags: united-states, life-insurance

No, I am not thinking about suicide, but I was wondering this as a curiosity question. If a person dies by an accident, they are covered by life insurance and their beneficiaries receive some amount of money. But if a person ends their life by suicide, are they covered by life insurance? Do their beneficiaries receive any amount of money?

---

**If you've found this question because you're thinking about suicide,** please know your life is worth more than insurance money. Please consider talking to someone, either [in the United States](https://suicidepreventionlifeline.org/talk-to-someone-now/) or [internationally](http://www.suicide.org/international-suicide-hotlines.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the United States, yes it will generally cover suicide. **However** there is usually a "[suicide clause](http://time.com/money/3117698/how-life-insurance-policies-deal-with-suicide/)":

> Usually, this clause states that no death benefit will be paid if the
>   insured commits suicide within two years of taking out a policy.
>
> Whenever an insured person replaces an existing life insurance policy
>   with a new one, the time clock for the suicide clause is set back to
>   zero and starts over again.

It also depends on the policy, state, etc.

Comment: So no benefit is paid if suicide happens within 2 years of taking out the policy, but is the inverse true? Must a payout happen if suicide occurs over 2 years after the policy?

Comment: It depends on your exact policy. When you buy life insurance, your insurance broker will tell you all the details.

Comment: Exactly. And there are times that a company will reject a benefit that's too high. I had no problem getting a $1M policy, but if I tried to get a $5M policy, I might arouse suspicion, especially since I'm retired. Suicide is awful, but usually done on impulse, not planned over 2 years in advance.

Comment: It would be kind of awkward to ask my broker how my policy covers death by suicide, but I suppose I'll look for it in the fine print out of morbid curiosity.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer And when suicide is planned over 2 years it's normally for medical reasons--which generally means death would have come fairly soon anyway.  (And it's pretty much moot as the medical condition would cause them to fail underwriting.)

Comment: The 2 year limit varies greatly, I believe it to be much higher in some states.

Comment: ..and there is always the risk that your misadventure will be misidentified as suicide.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - "medical condition would cause them to fail underwriting..." or greatly increase the premium. I know someone who had serious health issues and purchased a 1 yr insurance policy. The premium cost was approximately half of the payout, but I think they bought it to hedge something else that didn't kick in for another year. He passed away after 6 months and doubled their money on the short term policy. (Though presumably couldn't capitalize on something else as a result.)

Comment: @TTT Yeah, with serious health problems you're not going to get the insurance in the first place.  I wasn't talking about people who were ill when they got the insurance, but rather long-planned suicides--people with terminal illnesses who decide to end it when their health gets too bad.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that if you commit suicide *just to get the insurance money* then that will always invalidate the claim. (If they can show it).

Answer (score 6):

Suicide is one thing. And you are correct, it is two years. There are 6 other scenarios where life insurance does not pay out. https://www.truebluelifeinsurance.com/7-ways-life-insurance-will-not-pay-out/. These are important too.

1. Incontestability period. If you omitted or lied on the application, there is an incontestability clause where the insurance company can contest the payout if there is a claim in the first 2 years of the policy.
2. Exclusions. The policy may have exclusions in the contract where if the cause of death is from a dangerous activity, the policy does not pay out.
3. Illegal activities. If you die while committing a crime or participating in an illegal activity, the life insurance company can refuse to make a payment. For example, if you are killed while stealing a car, your beneficiary won’t be paid.
4. Act of war. This denies claims for civilians who are killed in wars or by acts of war, such as journalists whose job takes them into the midst of battle on a regular basis, or people who travel to regions of the world where there’s armed conflict.
5. Moving out of the country. Let’s say you take out a life insurance policy while you’re living in the United States, and then you move to another country. There could be a clause in the policy that excludes the payment of a death benefit if you are not living in the U.S. at the time of your death.
6. Fraud. If the company finds that you had certain health conditions or that you were involved in dangerous activities all the way back to the time you applied for coverage and you didn’t mention them, it can deny payment on the claim.

Disclosure - I am the CEO of the insurance firm cited in the link provided.

Comment: Links break. If you'd like your answer to remain, please summarize the '7 reasons' you are referencing.

Comment: Your affiliation to the mentioned site must also be disclosed directly in the answer. Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/behavior